# 1 model split into 3 tables in one view, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I have 1 model and database, with 3 different stored procedures which will sort the contents of the one main table into 3 smaller sub sections, outputting these as separate lists. I have created a view with 3 columns, for the results from the 3 stored procedures. Is it possible to add the 3 different stored procedures to the same view? See picture below for what I mean.

[image]

The stored procedures are all very basic `SELECT` statements, sort of like sorting the table into 3 different sub sections based off of how many criterias they have met.

My controller code now, where it doesn't reach the second and third views, as it can only return once. Is it possible to fic something here?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var none = context.Applications.SqlQuery("dbo.metNoCriteria").ToList();
                var basic = context.Applications.SqlQuery("dbo.metBasicCriteria").ToList();
                var more = context.Applications.SqlQuery("dbo.metMoreCriteria").ToList();
                return View(basic);
                
            }
            // View(db.Applications.ToList());
        }
```

**In other words** I am trying to split the contents of one database, into 3 sections, and outputting these as three different tables in one view, as seen above. (The image is not correct as the tables contain the same content; WHICH THEY WILL NOT). They will all three have the same Multilateral, Bilateral and Name columns, but the contents below will be different for the 3 colours.

Hope someone knows whether there is a possibility to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a viewModel class:

```
public class TablesViewModel
{
public List<NoneClass> NoneClassList {get; set;}
public List<BaseClass> BaseClassList {get; set;}
public List<MoreClass> MoreClassList {get; set;}
}
```

the action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
  {
        var model=new TablesViewModel();

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
  model.NoneClassList = context.Applications.SqlQuery("dbo.metNoCriteria").ToList();
model.BaseClassList = context.Applications.SqlQuery("dbo.metBasicCriteria").ToList();
 model.MoreClassList = context.Applications.SqlQuery("dbo.metMoreCriteria").ToList();
 
            }
            return View(model);
  }
```

Inside of the view use each list as a table source.

Comment: Thank you! Just was I was looking for